# Why does the group_concat bring all the product ids for every row

Tags: mysql, database, group-concat

here is my query which has a few joins and all works well except the GROUP_CONCAT(p.product_id) and the SUM(p.price) portion.

```
SELECT ts.name as main_name, tp.class_id, ts.step_number, GROUP_CONCAT(p.product_id) as product_id, SUM(p.price) as price
from template as t 
JOIN template_step as ts on ts.template_id=t.template_id 
JOIN template_product as tp on tp.template_id=ts.template_id 
JOIN product as p on p.product_id=tp.product_id 
JOIN product_description as pd on pd.product_id=p.product_id 
where t.template_id = '59' 
group by tp.class_id, ts.step_number 
ORDER by ts.step_number, tp.class_id
```

The problem is that the elements returned the product_ids and the sum field are repeating

Here is my data from the query

```
Networking  1   1    88,156,151,275,48,101,274,133,154,125,135,148,63,63    3070.0000
Networking  2   1    275,235,164,274,154,124,169,148,62,98,62,277,191,270   3695.0000
Networking  3   1    92,98,216,181,133,187,272,154,274,148,126,62,62,165    4970.0000
Back Office 1   2    63,88,156,151,275,48,101,274,133,154,125,135,148,63    3070.0000
Back Office 2   2    275,235,164,274,154,124,169,148,62,98,62,277,191,270   3695.0000
Back Office 3   2    62,165,92,98,216,181,133,187,272,154,274,148,126,62    4970.0000
Data Back   1   3    148,63,63,88,156,151,275,48,101,274,133,154,125,135    3070.0000
Data Back   2   3    270,275,235,164,274,154,124,169,148,62,98,62,277,191   3695.0000
Data Back   3   3    62,62,165,92,98,216,181,133,187,272,154,274,148,126    4970.0000
Kitchen     1   4    135,148,63,63,88,156,151,275,48,101,274,133,154,125    3070.0000
```

There should be only 1 or 2 product_id returned for each class. If there is any other information I can give to help others help me I can provide anything..db structure ..ext..

Comment: What are the relationships between the tables that are joined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) will not remove duplicate rows unless you use `DISTINCT`:

```
GROUP_CONCAT([DISTINCT] expr [,expr ...]
             [ORDER BY {unsigned_integer | col_name | expr}
                 [ASC | DESC] [,col_name ...]]
             [SEPARATOR str_val])
```

Comment: not only is the dups but if you see tp.class_id is repeating for the product_id and the sums are the same...which is wrong

Comment: Are your results correct without the `GROUP_CONCAT()` parts? Your `GROUP BY` clause omits many columns you retrieve in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Ok fixed the issue, the problem was in my join clause i needed two conditions JOIN template_product as tp on (tp.template_id=ts.template_id and ts.step_number=tp.step_number)